# Throw NPE if the source value is null in MapStruct

Tags: findbugs, mapstruct

MapStruct has NullValueMappingStrategy as RETURN_NULL by default. My requirement is that when source is null, I need to throw a NPE, similar to how @NonNull of lombok works.

But I guess there is no support for this as of now from MapStruct. So I have used @BeforeMapping to call a default method where I check for null and throw NPE.

```
@BeforeMapping
default void checkForNullArguments(Object anySource) {
    if(anySource == null){
        throw new NullPointerException("Source is null");
    }
}
```

So mapstruct implementation is generated the following way:

```
public Bar mapToBar(Foo foo) {
    this.checkForNullArguments(foo);
    if (foo == null) {
        return null;
    } else{
        ..... //Actual mapping logic
    }
}
```

With the above implementation NPE would be raised if the source is null but it is resulting in findbugs [RCN_REDUNDANT_NULLCHECK_WOULD_HAVE_BEEN_A_NPE](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html) error, which basically says that there is a redundant null check.
And there is no option to tell mapstruct to ignore null checks i.e. NullValueCheckStrategy only has ALWAYS & ON_IMPLICIT_CONVERSION(default value) but no IGNORE.

What is the best way to have the null check on source and throw NPE?

PS: Is there any way to use @NonNull of lombok combined with the MapStruct? I tried adding it to methods in the mapstruct interface, but these are getting ignored.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently an open [feature request](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1243) for supporting JSR 330 NonNull annotations.

At the moment you will have to ignore those redundant check warnings